# SQOOP integration with HIVE : Loading data in partitioned HIVE table

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop

I am importing data from mysql to HIVE using SQOOP on my local machine and below is the use case

1. Customer2 table exists in mysql as below

   ```
     mysql> select * from customer2;
     +-------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+---------    ----------+-----------------+---------------+----------------+------------------+
    | customer_id | customer_fname | customer_lname | customer_email | customer_password | customer_street | customer_city | customer_state | customer_zipcode |
    +-------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+-------------------+-----------------+---------------+----------------+------------------+
    |      100008 | Christine      | K              | NULL           | NULL                  | HK              | HK            | HK             | 19293            |
    |      100009 | Chris          | Taylor         | NULL           | NULL              | HK              | HK            | HK             | 1925             |
    |      100010 | Mark           | Jamiel         | NULL           | NULL              | HK              | HK            | HK             | 19294            |
    |      100011 | Tom            | Pride          | NULL           | NULL              | HK              | HK            | HK             | 19295            |
    |      100012 | Tom            | Heather        | NULL           | NULL              | CA              | CA            | CA             | 19295            |
    |      100013 | Maxim          | Calay          | NULL           | NULL              | CA              | CA            | CA             | 19295            |
    +-------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+-------------------+-----------------+---------------+----------------+------------------+
   ```
2. Same table customer2 exists in HIVE partitioned by customer_city as below :

   ```
   hive (sumitpawar)> describe customer2;
   OK
    col_name        data_type       comment
    customer_id           int                                         
    customer_fname          string                                      
    customer_lname          string                                      
    customer_email          string                                      
    customer_password       string                                      
    customer_zipcode        string                                      
    customer_city           string                                      

    Partition Information          
    col_name              data_type               comment             

    customer_city           string                                      
    Time taken: 0.098 seconds, Fetched: 12 row(s)
    hive (sumitpawar)>
   ```
3. Then I am using below SQOOP command to import the data to HIVE and expecting that the rows will move to appropriate partitions

**Sqoop**

```
sqoop import \
--options-file ./options_file.txt \
--table customer2 \
--columns  'customer_id,customer_fname,customer_lname,customer_email,customer_password,customer_zipcode' \
--hive-database sumitpawar \
--hive-import \
--null-string 'Empty' \
--null-non-string 0 \
-m 2 \
--mapreduce-job-name "JOB :import to hive from mysql"  \
--warehouse-dir "/PRACTICALS/SQOP/retail_db/increment_hive_mysql4" \
--hive-partition-key customer_city \
--hive-partition-value 'CA'
```

**content of options_file : option_file.txt**

```
 [cloudera@quickstart SQOOP]$ cat options_file.txt 
  #############################################
 --connect
 jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/retail_db

 --username
 root

 --password-file
 /PRACTICALS/SQOOP/password
 ############################################
```

**Execution log of SQOOP command**

```
    18/12/09 06:59:38 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1542647782962_0231
    18/12/09 06:59:49 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1542647782962_0231 running in uber mode : false
    18/12/09 06:59:49 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
    18/12/09 07:00:06 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 50% reduce 0%
    18/12/09 07:00:07 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
    18/12/09 07:00:07 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1542647782962_0231 completed successfully
    18/12/09 07:00:07 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 30
                File System Counters
                        FILE: Number of bytes read=0
                        FILE: Number of bytes written=311480
                        FILE: Number of read operations=0
                        FILE: Number of large read operations=0
                        FILE: Number of write operations=0
                        HDFS: Number of bytes read=253
                        HDFS: Number of bytes written=220
                        HDFS: Number of read operations=8
                        HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
                        HDFS: Number of write operations=4
                  Job Counters 
                        Launched map tasks=2
                        Other local map tasks=2
                        Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=29025
                        Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=0
                        Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=29025
                        Total vcore-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=29025
                        Total megabyte-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=29721600
             Map-Reduce Framework
                        Map input records=6
                        Map output records=6
                        Input split bytes=253
                        Spilled Records=0
                        Failed Shuffles=0
                        Merged Map outputs=0
                        GC time elapsed (ms)=417
                        CPU time spent (ms)=2390
                        Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=276865024
                        Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=3020857344
                        Total committed heap usage (bytes)=121765888
                  File Input Format Counters 
                        Bytes Read=0
                  File Output Format Counters 
                        Bytes Written=220
           18/12/09 07:00:07 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Transferred 220 bytes in 33.0333 seconds (6.66 bytes/sec)
           18/12/09 07:00:07 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Retrieved 6 records.
           18/12/09 07:00:07 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM `customer2` AS t LIMIT 1
           18/12/09 07:00:07 INFO hive.HiveImport: Loading uploaded data into Hive

           Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-common-1.1.0-cdh5.12.0.jar!/hive-log4j.properties
           OK
           Time taken: 3.016 seconds
           Loading data to table sumitpawar.customer2 partition (customer_city=CA)
           Partition sumitpawar.customer2{customer_city=CA} stats: [numFiles=2, numRows=0, totalSize=440, rawDataSize=0] 
           OK
           Time taken: 1.056 seconds

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

However, post execution on querying the table in HIVE , I could see NULL values for all the columns except customer_city

Output from HIVE table

```
hive (sumitpawar)> select * from customer2;
OK
+-------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+-----------   --------+-----------------+---------------+----------------+------------------+
| customer_id | customer_fname | customer_lname | customer_email |  customer_password | customer_street | customer_city | customer_state | customer_zipcode |
+-------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+-------------------+-----------------+---------------+----------------+------------------+
|      NULL | NULL      | NULL              | NULL           | NULL              |NULL              | NULL            | NULL             | NULL           |
+-------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+-------------------+-----------------+---------------+----------------+------------------+
```

Can someone let me know if there is anything wrong in the above and how can data  be loaded from SQOP w.r.t partitioned HIVE tables ?

Regards,
Sumit

Comment: `[numFiles=2, numRows=0, totalSize=440, rawDataSize=0]` can you check the content of the `hdfs` files. it shows `0` rows

Comment: how about using `--hive-table sumitpawar.customer2` option and removing `--warehouse-dir` option ?

Comment: can you try using `--query "select customer_id,customer_fname,customer_lname,customer_email,customer_password,customer_zipcode from customer2 where customer_city='CA' and \$CONDITIONS"` instead of `--columns` part and agree with @mangusta.And try running `MSCK REPAIR TABLE  customer2;`

Comment: Thanks mangusta and Subash. I tried option of adding --hive-table and the problem still exists, Option two of using --query with sqoop import is not valid as you will get error "Cannot specify --query and --table together." However when I view the file in name node GUI(localhost:50070) I could see the contents but querying it in hive gives he same null values. Problem still actual

Comment: can you post `hdfs dfs -ls /PRACTICALS/SQOP/retail_db/increment_hive_mysql4` just want to see if partition directory exist and files is in that directory.

Comment: Here it is     [cloudera@quickstart ~]$ hdfs dfs -ls /PRACTICALS/SQOOP/retail_db/increment_hive_mysql/customers
Found 3 items
-rw-r--r--   1 cloudera supergroup          0 2018-12-12 11:38 /PRACTICALS/SQOOP/retail_db/increment_hive_mysql/customers/_SUCCESS
-rw-r--r--   1 cloudera supergroup     475038 2018-12-12 11:38 /PRACTICALS/SQOOP/retail_db/increment_hive_mysql/customers/part-m-00000
-rw-r--r--   1 cloudera supergroup     478487 2018-12-12 11:38 /PRACTICALS/SQOOP/retail_db/increment_hive_mysql/customers/part-m-00001

Comment: run `hdfs dfs -rm /PRACTICALS/SQOOP/retail_db/increment_hive_mysql/customers` and `drop the table` and then recreate it and run your sqoop script.

Comment: please used either --table clause or --query.  you are not allowed to run with both clause together.
--query 'select customer_id,customer_fname,customer_lname,customer_email,customer_password,customer_zipcode  from customer2 where customer_city='CA' and \$CONDITIONS

Comment: Mahesh, I am not using --table and --query in sqoop import as it's not allowed. The problem is still actual.